# limit of a restricted functions

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Suppose that $f:A \to \mathbb R$ where $A \subseteq R$. Now let $g$ be a restricted function of $f$ in $B$ where $B \subseteq A$.

Now, there are two cases,

i) if $B$ is an open set in $A$, then for any $a \in B,$ $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)$ exists if and only if $\lim_{x \to a} g(x)$ exists.

ii) If $B$ is a closed set in $A$, then for any $a \in B,$ $\lim_{x \to a} g(x)$ exists if $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)$ exists.

iii) $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)$ need not exist if $\lim_{x \to a} g(x)$ exist at $a$.

Since $g$ is a restriction of $f$ in $B$, then for any $b \in B$, $f$ and $g$ functions have same value, then how does restriction affects the limit? I tried many examples to understand the concept but cannot understand it properly.

Reference:Introduction to Real Analysis by Bartle, Sherbert.

Answer (score 1):

Let A= $\mathbb{R}$, Let B = $\mathbb{R^-}$

f:$\mathbb{R}$ $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb{R}$, 
g:$\mathbb{R^-}$ $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb{R}$

if f(x) = $\left\lbrace{0, x\le 0\\1, x >0}\right.$,

g(x) = 0

consider the limit at 0

Comment: Great....is $R^{-}$ closed in $R$?

Comment: No.  It is (-infinity, 0).  This example applies more to the iii, but provides info for the other parts.

Comment: if it is open, then i) follows (i.e) if and only if statements. Actually the example contradicts the (i), statement (iii) is true only when B is closed in A.

Comment: Thanks for the example, now i understood the concept. 0 is not in $\mathbb R^{-}$

Comment: For i, 0 $\notin$ B

Comment: Sorry, i was driving to work.  Just saw your comment.  Correct.